# A complex sequence that has $n$ limit points, for any natural number $n$;

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to find examples of a sequence that has $n$ limit points, for any given integer $n$.

One example I found is $$1,2, \dots, n, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, \dots, \frac{2n+1}{2},\dots,\frac{k+1}{k},\frac{2k+1}{k},\dots,\frac{nk+1}{k},\dots$$

However, I don't understand how this sequence has $n$ limit points. 
Could anyone explain this to me? Also, what other sequences may there be?

Comment: Why not the simpler sequence $1,2,\ldots, n, 1,2,\ldots, n,1,2,\ldots$? Or $e^{2k\pi i/n}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The definition of a limit point of a set $A$ used here is every deleted neighborhood of the limit point contains a point of $A$. So the set would need to be infinite. I think you've interpreted it as the limit of a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each integer $j$ between $1$ and $n$
$$
\frac{j\,k+1}{k},\quad k\ge1
$$
is a subsequence and converges to $j$.